# JavaFX webview crash with Facebook website

Tags: java, facebook, javafx

I have a JavaFX application with JavaFX 8 and I need to include Facebook login option to my users. I used "RestFB" library to work with Facebook and WebView to open Facebook website to do the login step. However sometimes the application crash when the user are using the Facebook website (like typing the user or password) and it's closed directly because the JVM die. This is the summary of the error when JVM die.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001367a637b, pid=93595, tid=0x0000000000000307
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjfxwebkit.dylib+0x107937b]  JSC::MarkedBlock::clearMarks()+0xb
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /XXX/YYYY/hs_err_pid93595.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I tested the same code in OSx and Windows 7 with the same result, the problem doesn't happen always but I don't know how can I fix that.

I checked some bugs about JVM but really I am not sure if the problem is the same or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you report the bug as described? I fear there is not much more that you could do.

Comment: I didn't report it, I guess that this bug was reported before but with another websites :( I will try to check if the bug is fixed with newer versions of JavaFX but could be difficult migrate all our clients to it.